# How to get click event object data from dynamically created button using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am collecting page button click events. Normally I am collecting the objects from statically created DOM elements. By using:

```
 $('input[type=button]').each(function () {
              $(this).bind('click', function () {
                  Console.log(this);
              });
          });
```

But when I add a new button dynamically like:

```
 vvar newBtn = document.createElement('input');
      newBtn.type = 'button';
      newBtn.setAttribute('id', 'JgenerateBtn');
      newBtn.setAttribute('value', 'JgenerateBtn');
      newBtn.onclick = function () { alert('javascript dynamically created button'); };
      var holderDiv = document.getElementById('holder');
      holderDiv.appendChild(newBtn);
```

after this code, New Button is created and event also triggering, but I'm not able to get the Event object by using, same above code.

```
 $('input[type=button]').each(function () {
          $(this).bind('click', function () {
              Console.log(this);
          });
      });
```

Please provide suggestion to get the dynamically created elements event object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding events on dynamically added elements. Like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=button]', function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

This is just for simple example, it is better to bind it on element closer to your button that is already on page when it first loads rather than on `document`.

Comment: Yes, plus `bind` is deprecated AFAIK.

Comment: Why its not dynamically created elements objects is not logged in my code..can u explain difference between this?

Comment: @chandramohan Because events can only be bound to an element that are existing on page when it loads, so dynamically added elements are not selected on your code. Read `Direct and Delegated events` on the `on()` link above to better understand.

Comment: No prob. Hope you get something from my poor explanation. :)

Comment: Very nice! Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#holder').on('click', ':button', function(event) {
    alert('testlink'); 
});
```

This will attach your event to any button within the `#holder` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

More info here:-

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

The event object is handed to your click handler as the first argument.

```
$('input[type=button]').each(function () {
    $(this).bind('click', function (event) {
        Console.log(event);
    });
});
```